# prove or disprove - $p(x)$ = $\sum_0^n$ $a_iX^i$ $c,d,a_i \in $ Z , $n \in N$ then c-d|p(c)-p(d)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Prove or disprove that if $p(x)$ = $\sum \limits _{i=0} ^n a_i X^i$ with $a_i  \in \Bbb Z$ and if $c, d \in \Bbb Z$, then $ c-d \space | \space p(c)-p(d)$.

What I tried: I know both sums can start from $1$ because when $i = 0$ both sides are same. Then, when starting the sums from $1$ I know $c \space | \space p(c)$ and $d \space | \space p(d)$. Now I'm stuck... My idea was that maybe because of the line above I can assume that $c-d \space | \space p(c)-p(d)$ but I'm not sure.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Observe: $c-d\mid c^m-d^m$ for all natural numbers $m$.

Comment: It is not true that if $a\mid b$ and $c\mid d$ then $a-c\mid b-d$.  For example, when $a=7$, $b=14$, $c=5$, $d=5$, then $7\mid 14$ and $5\mid 5$, but $2\nmid 9$.

Comment: how can i prove that ? i couldn't find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Try factoring $c^m-d^m$.  Let's consider the case where $m=4$.  First, we write
$$
c^4-d^4=(c-d)(\cdots)
$$
(here the $(\cdots)$ means that we're trying to figure out what should be in this product).  Since there is a term $c^4$, we should have a $c^3$ in the unknown factor.  Therefore,
$$
c^4-d^4=(c-d)(c^3+\cdots)=c^4-c^3d+(c-d)(\cdots).
$$
The RHS now has a term $-c^3d$, which shouldn't appear.  So this term must cancel somehow.  We can cancel it by adding $c^3d$ or by introducing a $c^2d$ in the unknown factor because $c^2d\cdot c=c^3d$.  Therefore
$$
c^4-d^4=(c-d)(c^3+c^2d+\cdots)=c^4-c^2d^2+(c-d)(\cdots).
$$
We now get rid of the $-c^2d^2$ by introducing a $cd^2$ in the sum to get
$$
c^4-d^4=(c-d)(c^3+c^2d+cd^2+\cdots)=c^4-cd^3+(c-d)(\cdots).
$$
To get rid of the $-cd^3$, we introduce a $d^3$ in the unknown factor to get
$$
c^4-d^4=(c-d)(c^3+c^2d+cd^2+d^3\cdots)=c^4-d^4+(c-d)(\cdots).
$$
This gives exactly what we're looking for, so the remainder of the unknown factor must be zero.  In summary:
$$
c^4-d^4=(c-d)(c^3+c^2d+cd^2+d^3).
$$

For the general case, try this technique for a few values of $m$ and try to see the pattern.  You may be familiar with the cases where $m=2$ or $m=3$ as the difference of squares or cubes, respectively.  In general, this idea works to factor many different polynomials (and is somewhat more hands-on than other options).